# Refactor without -XScopedTypeVariables

Tags: haskell

I have a function (in a module) that returns `IO (Maybe a)` where a is an instance of the `Serialize`.

From my main Program I call this as follows:

```
 msg <- fun token
 print msg
```

and get the error

```
Ambiguous type variable `a0' in the constraints:
      (Data.Serialize.Serialize a0) arising from a use of `foo'
                                    at test_00.hs:13:15-19
      (Show a0) arising from a use of `print' at test_00.hs:17:9-13
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
```

I know exactly what the problem is and I can fix it using -XScopedTypeVariables and some changes in how I call my library function as follows:

```
(msg :: Maybe String) <- cwPop token
print msg
```

However, I would rather like to avoid the ScopedTypeVariables  and wonder where it is any way that I can test if msg is member of the show class and then print it. If not do something else .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can give a type signature to the expression on the right hand side of the `<-` without extensions,

```
msg <- fun token :: IO (Maybe String)
print msg
```

(I have made the indentation so that `print` and `msg` aren't arguments to `fun` anymore, your indentation seemed to be broken).

Comment: Indentation is in deed broken bed it is a copy & paste out of a larger piece of code of course.

Comment: Since my library does not modify the data (except serializing & deserializing it); - would data.typeable be a possibility to get around the need to specify a type at all?

Comment: No, the type must be statically determined, so `print` can call the right `show` function. And if the function/action has polymorphic return type, it must know which type to produce to know e.g. how many bytes to read when deserializing. `Typeable` allows to compare the type of runtime objects to statically known types, not to determine at runtime, which type to produce.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility:

```
msg <- fun token
print (msg :: Maybe String)
```

(There is no dynamic typing going on here, despite what it may look like -- we just needed to get the type checker some more information, how is a matter of style)